# VBA/macro to move rows to various other sheets automatically

Tags: vba, excel

Getting familiar with VBA/Macro’s but still new and struggling. I’ve been able to piece together stuff by looking up examples on youtube videos and playing around with other codes posted online but I’m stuck and need major help

I’ve got four sheets on my workbook. All of them have the same layout, the first column is my header and has a filter. All the columns after L are hidden/deleted.

I copy/paste information into the first sheet (Feb – Monitor), from an application, "an example is on the text to column sheet). I have a macro to move everything to the correct columns which is run on the first sheet.

I’d like a macro for the first sheet so that when it’s run, it’ll do the following;

Look at information in column G and move them to the appropriate sheets in the next empty row.

Pending – Move anything that is “DA” or “I” to this sheet
Accepted - Move anything that is “AC” to this sheet
Released – Move anything that is “RL” to this sheet.

One thing to point out, there are blank spaces that appear in some of the cells in column G next to the characters ie “T “ (two blank spaces after T) or “RT “ (one blank space after RT)

For the other sheets, I’d like to know how to modify the code I have in “Module1” to automatically move rows for just the Pending, Accepted, and Released sheets to other sheets once you key in the specific status. I’ve played around with the code and can get it to work but it overwrites the first row instead of moving it an empty row.

Feb - Monitor - Anything keyed in as RT, T, RE, RJ is moved to the first sheet
Pending - Anything keyed in as DA or I moves to this sheet
Accepted - Anything keyed in as AC moves to this sheet.
Released - Anything keyed in as RL moves to this sheet.

Link to the spreadsheet on google drive. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6fek87_mXuEMnVCRUtobVVqQU0

Much appreciated

Comment: Why are all of your column As blank?  Not even a field name in row 1?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of if's in that answer.  Mostly in the "set ws" section.  To the right of each "set" command I put the strings that should be sent to those pages.  Are all of those correct?  And if so, when you import your data is it imported to  Worksheets("Feb - Monitor")?  And that is the main page you are searching for strings in column G?  If all of that is correct then this should work for you.  Make a copy of your workbook and try it in the copy first.  Create a plain module in the VBA editor and paste this into it.  It will copy rows based on strings found in column G and paste them into the appropriate pages.  If you want to remove those rows from  Worksheets("Feb - Monitor") after they have been copied to other pages then uncomment (remove the ') from nextRow = 2 on down.

```
Sub Macro1()
'Feb - Monitor - Anything keyed in as RT, T, RE, RJ
'is moved to the first sheet Pending -
'Anything keyed in as DA or I moves to this sheet Accepted -
'Anything keyed in as AC moves to this sheet. Released -
'Anything keyed in as RL moves to this sheet.

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim nextRow As Long
Dim myArray() As Variant


Set ws1 = Worksheets("Feb - Monitor") '  RT, T, RE, RJ
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Pending") '   DA, I
Set ws3 = Worksheets("Accepted") '  AC
Set ws4 = Worksheets("Released") '  RL

lastRow = ws1.Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row

myArray = ws1.Range("G2:G" & lastRow)


 For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    If InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "T") > 0 And InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "RT") = 0 Or _
        InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "RT") > 0 Or InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "RE") > 0 Or _
        InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "RJ") > 0 Then
        ' These need to stay on Worksheets("Feb - Monitor") so we do nothing
        ' The reason I added this loop is in case I misunderstood your need
        ' This loop is not necessary if we are'nt moving them
    End If
    If InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "DA") > 0 Or InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "I") > 0 Then ' send to "Pending"
        nextRow = ws2.Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ws1.Rows(i + 1).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & nextRow)
    End If
    If InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "AC") > 0 Then ' send to "Accepted"
        nextRow = ws3.Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws1.Rows(i + 1).Copy Destination:=ws3.Range("A" & nextRow)
    End If
    If InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "RL") > 0 Then ' send to "Released"
        nextRow = ws4.Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws1.Rows(i + 1).Copy Destination:=ws4.Range("A" & nextRow)
    End If

Next i


'*********************************************
'   The following code deletes all rows on worksheets("Feb - Monotor)
'   that are not RT, T, RE, RJ
'   You can uncomment it if you want to do that

'nextRow = 2
'For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
'    nextRow = nextRow + 1
'    If InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "DA") > 0 Or InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "I") > 0 _
'        Or InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "AC") Or InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "RL") > 0 Then
'        nextRow = nextRow - 1
'        Debug.Print i, myArray(i, 1), nextRow
'        ws1.Rows(nextRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
'    End If
'Next i

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing
Set ws3 = Nothing
Set ws4 = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. Would I copy/paste this code to the first sheet or create a new module for it?

Comment: There is a lot of if's in that answer.  Mostly in the "set ws" section.  To the right of each set I put the strings that should be sent to that page.

Comment: see the dited answer